# Template parameters SFINAE not using a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, enable-if, non-type

Why is such a construct disallowed in C++:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<std::enable_if_t<true, bool> = true>
void fn() {}

template<std::enable_if_t<false, bool> = true>
void fn() {}

int main()
{
    fn();
    return 0;
}
```

It seems like the compiler is complaining about the fact that `enable_if` is missing its template argument I believe? Is there a way to achieve the behaviour above without introducing another template parameter set to some default value for example?

Comment: You may have simplified a little too much. There's no point in declaring something that can never be used.

Comment: It's not [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) if there is no S!

Comment: @aschepler I get that point, I am just curious how the above or something similar can be made to compile, if at all.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Fair point. I still would like to achieve a behaviour similar to partial specialization, assuming the second would be simply not a defined specialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a template parameter to substitute in order for SFINAE to take place. So create a dummy template parameter and a dummy trait that will take it and returns true and false respectively.

```
template<class T>
constexpr bool always_true = true;
template<class T>
constexpr bool always_false = false;

template<class T=void, std::enable_if_t<always_true<T>>* = nullptr>
void fn() {}

template<class T=void, std::enable_if_t<always_false<T>>* = nullptr>
void fn() {}
```

Comment: Can't get rid of the `T` I assume?

Comment: @lightxbulb Yes, by just defining a single function named `fn`. But there's no way to avoid this if you want to use SFINAE.

Comment: I don't particularly want to use SFINAE but rather partial function specialization, unfortunately C++ doesn't support this.

Comment: You could define two overloads of `fn` (`void fn(std::true_type) {}` and `void fn(std::false_type) = delete`). It uses overloading instead of specialisation. I think that's the best you can do if you still want two functions. You call it as `fn(std::true_type{}); fn(std::false_type{})`.